# creating buttons in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, button

I have created a database and am looking to create buttons for the select, delete and update functions but I am very new and am not sure how to make this happen?  I would really like them to all be in one area so the table can be updated in one spot?

Here is my code - select data

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Franchise_Call_Log");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM caller_info");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['Firstname'] . " " . $row['Lastname'];
echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Update

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Your records have been updated</h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Franchise_Call_Log");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE caller_info SET Franchise='Valpak'
WHERE Firstname='Peter' AND Lastname='Griffin'");

mysqli_close($con);
?> 

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Record has been updated</h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Franchise_Call_log");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="DELETE FROM caller_info (Firstname, Lastname, Franchise)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[franchise]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record deleted";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what other code you may need, I have the create tables, database etc.  I am VERY new at this and am hoping you can help me.  Thank You!

Comment: You're gonna need to use some input elements my friend :)  Go ahead and read up on HTML forms and I think the rest will start to make a lot more sense: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: You want to work through a tutorial that introduces you to this stuff systematically. This is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, which is geared towards specific technical questions

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_update_php.htm